# Patanjali yoga asana

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras, patanjali

Well, I was reading a book by Samuel Aun Weor. When I came across this practise anulom-vilom with toning sounds. Here is the link :

*https://glorian.org/books/the-yellow-book/christic-egyptian-pranayama*

The mantra or tones he mentions in this book along with this pranayama is something I cannot find anywhere else. Is the author mistaken or am I lacking in research?

This video also has the same content :

*https://youtu.be/DihZ8QR3uuU*

Comment: I am not sure of the other Aksharas, but Ham and  Sa is the sound which automatically generates when we breathe in and breathe out.  It is well covered in Vijyanbhairava Tantra. There is an excerpt by Swami Lakshmanjoo Maharaj, You may check this here: https://www.lakshmanjooacademy.org/vijnana-bhairava-verse-24/

Comment: Not a forum for the veracity of youtube videos. I would recommend that you contact the author of the video as to his purported sources.